# Disable wp_enqueue_style for theme on wp-admin

Tags: theme-development, wp-enqueue-style

At this moment I use functions as described in the "Theme handbook" from the WordPress site. The problem is that the stylesheet is loading on the backend pages too and it affects the layout of the backend pages. This behavior is not wanted.

The code I use to load the stylesheet -> https://pastebin.com/rAMZSu3u

Does anyone know a way/method to load the stylesheet only on the frontend so the wp-admin backend does not get affected?

Note: The CSS is compiled with scssphp when the $dev variable is set to true.

Comment: The Codeshare page is empty. Please place the code here.

Comment: I changed it to Pastebin. The question has been updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a conditional tag `is_admin()` which checks are you in the Administration Panel or Frontend. So,

```
if( !is_admin() ) {
    wp_enqueue_style(
        'css-minified',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'style.css',
        [],
        null,
        'all'
    );
    wp_enqueue_style(
        'font-awesome',
        'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css',
        [],
        null,
        'all'
    );
}
```

See [is_admin()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_admin).

Answer (score 2):

Your styles should be enqueued on the `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook for the public side or `admin_enqueue_scripts` for the admin side.

```
//* Enqueue public scripts and style
function wpse_264511_wp_enqueue_scripts {
    wp_enqueue_style( $handle, $src = '', $deps = array(), $ver = false, $media = 'all' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse_264511_wp_enqueue_scripts' );

//* Enqueue admin scripts and style
function wpse_264511_admin_enqueue_scripts {
    wp_enqueue_style( $handle, $src = '', $deps = array(), $ver = false, $media = 'all' );
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse_264511_admin_enqueue_scripts' );
```